# the srcSliceY parameter in sws_scale function of ffmpeg library

Tags: ffmpeg, scale

Almost everywhere I looked, the srcSliceY value is set to 0.
In the documentation it is wrriten:

```
c            the scaling context previously created with sws_getContext()
srcSlice    the array containing the pointers to the planes of the source slice
srcStride   the array containing the strides for each plane of the source image
srcSliceY   the position in the source image of the slice to process, that is the number (counted starting from zero) in the image of the first row of the slice
...
```

It is unclear to me what it means "the source image". Does it mean the source slice ? There is no parameter called "source image".

I wrote this code:

```
SwsContext *ctx = sws_getContext(width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8,
                                         dwidth, dheight, AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8,
                                         SWS_BILINEAR, NULL, NULL, NULL);


const uint8_t* srcSlice[1] = { pSrc};
const int srcStride[1] = { width };
int srcSliceH = height;
const int   dstStride[1] = { dwidth };

printf("srcStride=%d, height =%d\n",srcStride[0],srcSliceH);
for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
  int t = sws_scale(ctx, srcSlice, srcStride, i, srcSliceH, &pDst, dstStride);
  if(t != 0)
    printf("i=%d t= %d\n",i,t);
}
```

I get the output:

```
srcStride=384, height =30
[swscaler @ 0x1b0ba60] Warning: data is not aligned! This can lead to a speedloss
i=0 t= 2
i=4 t= 1
i=14 t= 1
i=24 t= 1
i=33 t= 1
i=43 t= 1
i=52 t= 1
i=62 t= 1
i=72 t= 1
i=81 t= 1
i=91 t= 1
```

Looking at the source code of sws_scale, it returns 0 upon error or invalid input. So I conclude that for most values of srcSliceY in the iteration the sws_returns error. But it is unclear what is valid.

Answer (score 0):

So after doing some more experiments I think I figured it out. The `srcSliceY` and the `srcSliceH` parameters for `sws_scale` should sum up to `srcH` parameter of `sws_getContext`.

Then `sws_scale` keeps the ratio  `dstH : srcH` parameters of `sws_getContext` when deciding the height of the output slice. Such that if `dh` is the return value of `sws_scale` then:

`dstH : srcH` ~=  `dh : srcSliceH`

So, the following code:

```
int sws_scale_test(){

  int srcW = 1000;
  int srcH = 1000;
  int dstW = 2000;
  int dstH = 3000;

  unsigned char* pSrc = (unsigned char*)malloc(srcW*srcH);
  unsigned char* pDst = (unsigned char*)malloc(dstW*dstH);

  SwsContext *ctx = sws_getContext(srcW,srcH, AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8, dstW,dstH, AV_PIX_FMT_GRAY8, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

  const uint8_t* srcSlice[4] = { pSrc,NULL,NULL,NULL};
  const int srcStride[4] = { srcW,0,0,0 };
  int srcSliceY = 0;

  uint8_t* dst[4] = { pDst,NULL,NULL,NULL };
  const int  dstStride[4] = { dstW,0,0,0};

  printf("dstH/srcH = %f\n",((double)dstH)/ ((double)srcH)  );

  for(int i=1;srcH>i;i = 2*i){
    int srcSliceH = srcH-i;
    int dh = sws_scale(ctx, srcSlice, srcStride, i, srcSliceH, dst, dstStride);
    if(dh != 0)
      printf(" dt/srcH = %f\n",i,srcSliceH,dh, ((double)dh)/((double)    (srcSliceH)) );    
  }
  return 0;
}
```

prints:

```
dstH/srcH = 3.000000
dt/srcH = 2.994995
dt/srcH = 2.994990
dt/srcH = 2.994980
dt/srcH = 2.994960
dt/srcH = 2.994919
dt/srcH = 2.994835
dt/srcH = 2.994658
dt/srcH = 2.994266
dt/srcH = 2.993280
dt/srcH = 2.989754
```